# Space of bounded linear operators might fail to be a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

I tried to show that the space of bounded linear operators $B(X,Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces, might fail to be a Banach space. To show this, I considered the space $X = \ell^1 (\mathbb{N})$ and Y as the space of sequences of scalars with only finitely many non-zero terms. Y is considered as a subspace of $\ell^1 (\mathbb{N})$, i.e., $(Y, \|\cdot\|_1)$ is a normed space.

My approach was the following:

Since $\ell^1 (\mathbb{N})$ is complete, the space $B(\ell^1 (\mathbb{N}), \ell^1 (\mathbb{N}))$ is complete. Consider the operators $T_n : \ell^1 (\mathbb(N)) \to \ell^1 (\mathbb{N})$ given by $T_n x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n,0,0,0, ...)$. Then $T_n \in B(\ell^1 (\mathbb{N}), \ell^1 (\mathbb{N}))$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $T_n \to I$ as $n \to \infty$, where $I$ denotes the identity operator. Thus $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $B(\ell^1 (\mathbb{N}), \ell^1 (\mathbb{N}))$. Since $T_n \in B(\ell^1 (\mathbb{N}), Y)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ forms a Cauchy sequence in $B(\ell^1 (\mathbb{N}), Y)$. However, $I \notin B(\ell^1 (\mathbb{N}), Y)$. Thus $B(\ell^1 (\mathbb{N}), Y)$ is not a closed subspace of $B(\ell^1 (\mathbb{N}), \ell^1 (\mathbb{N}))$, and hence not complete.

I think the approach is correct, but I would appreciate it if someone could comment on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $T_n \to I$. They only converge pointwise, but not in the operator norm.

Here is an easier proof:

Let $Y$ be an incomplete normed space and let $X$ be the scalar field. Then $B(X,Y)$ is isometric to $Y$, so it is incomplete.

Comment: I am aware of the easier proof, but I would like to proof it using the given spaces X and Y as this is one of the exercises of a book I am working through. Could I do this using the operators $T_n$ defined above?

Comment: @user342207, sure. Take $S_n (x_k)_{k=1}^\infty = T_n( \tfrac{1}{2^k} x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$. Then $S_n$ converge in the operator norm to $S$ given by $S(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty = ( \tfrac{1}{2^k} x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, as my mistake was in the convergence in the operator norm. Using the operators $S$ and $S_n$, it follows that $\| (S - S_n) x \|_1 = \sum_{j = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^j} |x_j| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \|x\|_1$. Taking the supremum over all $x$ on the unit sphere and letting $n \to \infty$, it follows that $\| S - S_n \|_{op} \to 0$.

Comment: @user342207, indeed :-)